# How can I copy a single file and maintain directory structure?

Tags: linux, file-management

How can I do this on the command line?

e.g. copy `/dir/another/file` to `/tmp/` so I have `/tmp/dir/another/file`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
cp --parents /dir/another/file /tmp
```

will do exactly what you want.

Comment: any ideas for os/x?  `--parents` do not live here ;(

Comment: tar or rsync? See the other two answers :-)

Comment: For macOS you can, via homebrew, install `brew install coreutils` and use `gcp --parents /dir/another/file /tmp`

Answer (score 5):

[rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) can be a good help for this :

```
rsync -Ravz my/first/dir/file.txt another_dir
```

will gave as result

```
another_dir/my/first/dir/file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tar` to preserve paths while copying files:

```
tar cf - /dir/another/file | (cd /tmp && tar xf -)
```